# Assertions in Windows Services

Tags: c++, windows-services, assertions

I'd like to assert using _ASSERTE in a backend Windows service code. But as I understand, the default behaviour will hang the service because of the message box.

What is the best way to safely do assertions in a Windows service?

Edit:
I should've mentioned that code should still use the normal behaviour, if running in the console mode; for example when being unit tested.

Comment: What would you like the assertion to do? It's really a problem-specific solution as some services should fail hard on assertions and some should merely log an error and some should email NASA and alert them to an imminent space invasion.

Comment: I guess emailing NASA doesn't go well with Assertions ;). Because as you know, it's used during testing the debug version of the application. I'd like to get the basic benefit of an assert; get notified (with something obvious, that's hard to ignore) when some ASSERT fails. Because there will be no message box to allow Ignoreing the message, or breaking..etc. I think maybe an option in a configuration file or so will specify how to act to failed assertions; stop the service, or not. But most importantly, as I said, I'd like to know that something went wrong once it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write your own assert function.

```
void assert(bool condition)
{
    //Stop service and log failure to event log here ;)
}
```

Comment: mmm, I think logging to the event log won't grab attention as much as the message box used to do.

Comment: @haggag: you could keep a normal process to show the message box, and send it commands from the service.

Comment: @haggag: You specifically asked it *not* to show a message box. What do you want me to do? :P Besides, if there's an assertion failure, usually that indicates that something is horribly wrong with the service and that it should terminate.